# docker /bin/sh: 1: [: “npm”,: unexpected operator while deploying node app

Tags: node.js, docker

Attempting containerize a node app. The app runs fine locally, but when deploying with docker the app won't run. What am I doing wrong?

Error log:

```
/bin/sh: 1: [: “npm”,: unexpected operator
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "./bin/www" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: app_container
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

.bin/www

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('recipe-calendar:server');
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
}, app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: I assume you are running `docker-compose up`?

can you show what is in `./bin/www`?

Comment: fyi `[` is the same as the linux `test` command, and it expects some operator

Comment: @RedTwoon i added bin/www code to question. To run docker compose I'm actually clicking "run" in phpstorm IDE, but I tried ``docker-compose up`` and got the same error

Comment: Typically that specific error is caused by having "curly" quotes in a Dockerfile `CMD` line, but it needs to be "straight" quotes; `CMD [ "npm", ... ]` produces that error when you have the wrong kind of quotes.  That error doesn't quite match the Dockerfile you posted, though.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes that doesn't match since I;m not using "npm" in CMD. I'm using "node"